# AttributeError: Object has no attribute called

Tags: python, oop

I thought that if an attribute was give 'self.' then even if the attribute wasn't set up in a method, it could be used in other methods. However, I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'QuizBrain' object has no attribute 'user_r'
```

this is my full code:

```
question_data = [
    {"text": "A slug's blood is green.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "The loudest animal is the African Elephant.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are entitled to a state funeral.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.",
        "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.", "answer": "True"}
]


class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self, q_list, a_list):
        self.question_list = q_list
        self.answer_list = a_list
        self.current_number = 0

    def next_question(self):
        question = self.question_list[self.current_number]
        context_question_number = self.current_number + 1
        self.user_r = input(
            (f'Q.{context_question_number}: {question} True or False '))
        self.current_number += 1

    def still_have_questions(self):
        return(self.current_number < len(self.question_list))

    def check_answer(self):

        self.current_answer = self.answer_list[self.current_number]
        if self.user_r == self.current_answer:
            return True
        elif self.user_r != self.current_answer:
            print(
                "the answer is {}, you got {} questions right" .format(self.current_answer, self.current_number))
            return False


list_of_questions = []
list_of_answers = []

for line in question_data:
    question_line = line['text']
    list_of_questions.append(question_line)

for line in question_data:
    answer_line = line['answer']
    list_of_answers.append(answer_line)


quiz_brain = QuizBrain(list_of_questions, list_of_answers)

while quiz_brain.still_have_questions() and quiz_brain.check_answer():
    quiz_brain.next_question()
    quiz_brain.check_answer()
```

Do I have to mention the user_r attribute in the **init** part?

Comment: You are calling `check_answer`, which tries to read `self.user_r`, before you have called `next_question`, which writes `self.user_r`.

Comment: @khelwood thank you! In this case, I want the program to discontinue when check_answer returns False or still_have_questions reads False. If we can't call check_answer before next_question, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `check_answer`, which tries to read `self.user_r`, before you have called `next_question`, which writes `self.user_r`.

Here is a way you can avoid calling `check_answer` before you have called `next_question`:

```
while quiz_brain.still_have_questions():
    quiz_brain.next_question()
    if not quiz_brain.check_answer():
        break
```